# Azure Function data to Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, httpclient

I have created an Azure function which fetches data from a particular API. I want to now insert the data fetch from API in MONGO database but I have no idea how to proceed.

Please help!!

Also let me know if there is any other information needed

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to create a mongo db database either in azure or in mongo and get the connection string of the database. In case of azure create a azure cosmos db api for mongo dB resource from the portal and get the connection string.

[image]

- Theoretically here we create a client object (here we also pass the connection string) which will connect to the mongo db then we will use the client to create and manipulate the database.
- Under the quickstart tab of the azure mongo dB you will find language specific ways to create the client and ways to change the database.

[image]

- Now using the connection string, we can connect to the mongo dB. Since you are using azure function use the application setting to store the connection string and use them as an environment variable. The application setting is under configuration tab.

[image]

Refer this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb) by Robert Walters